# Confused by the defintion of bounded sets in normed spaces.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

In our functional analysis class we defined a set $M$ on a metric space $(X,d)$ as bounded if sup$_{x,y \in M} d(x,y) < \infty$. Or, equivalently, $M$ is bounded if there exists a $y \in M$ such that sup$_{x \in M} d(x,y) < \infty$.

Later, we proved that a linear operator (between normed vector spaces) is bounded if and only if the image of bounded sets is bounded. The proof starts like this: Let $M$ be bounded, then sup$_{x \in M} \lVert x \rVert < \infty$....

Why ist this always true for a bounded set? I understand that this holds if $d(x,y) := \lVert x-y\rVert$ but this does not have to be the case for an arbitrary metric, right?

Comment: In an arbitrary metric space there isn't a norm, so that would make sense. But in a **normed** space, a bounded set satisfies $\sum_{x\in M} \|x\| < \infty$.

Comment: But why? Couldn't I have a normed space with a metric that doesn't have anything to do with the norm? Like $(X,d, \lVert . \rVert)$ but $d$ and $\lVert . \rVert$ are totally unrelated?

Comment: Yes you could, and it could also have a group structure and a partial order structure, all unrelated, and since they are unrelated it doesn't make sense to bring one to the discussion of the other.

Comment: When dealing with a normed linear space, it comes with its own canonical metric: $d(x, y) = \|x - y\|$. All the topological and bornological terms like convergence, boundedness, continuity, etc, etc, all spring from this metric. Equipping a vector space with an abstract metric, when it was previously equipped with a norm, would turn the set into a (different) metric space, not a normed linear space.

Comment: @jjagmath I guess you meant $\sup_{x\in M}\|x\|<\infty.$

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Yes, thank you.